# Using fuzzy regex (in Python) to correct spelling

Tags: python, regex

I have an array of frequent words in the text I am an analyzing, and I intend to use regex fuzzing matching to replace any misspellings of them.

I know I could loop over them like:

```
import regex as re

edits = 1
my_arr = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
my_text = 'this is my text with wrd1 in it'

for word in my_arr:
    r_pattern = '(' + word + ')' + '){e<=' + str(edits) + '}'
    my_text = re.sub(r_pattern, word, my_text)
```

But is there a way to use `regex.sub` to do this with one line? i.e. so my pattern could look something like

```
r_pattern = '(word1|word2|word3){e<=1}'
```

Comment: you could call `regex.sub` with a replacement function as second argument instead of a string, but I don't think `regex` provides a way to retrieve the word it was trying to match when it fuzzily matched, so you would likely have to implement the fuzzy->correct mapping yourself

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
import regex as re

def repl(matchObj):
    return str(matchObj.lastgroup)

edits = 1
my_arr = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
my_text = 'this is my text with wrd3 in it'

r_pattern = ""
for i in range(len(my_arr)):
    if i == len(my_arr)-1:
        r_pattern += '(?P<' + my_arr[i] + '>' + my_arr[i] + '){e<=' + str(edits) + '}'
    else:
        r_pattern += '(?P<' + my_arr[i] + '>' + my_arr[i] + '){e<=' + str(edits) + '}|'

r = re.compile(r_pattern)
my_text = re.sub(r, repl, my_text)
print (my_text)
```

It uses the lastgroup attribute of the match object which tells you which group caused the substitution to trigger.
This should scale well with a larger array if you need it to, assuming there isn't a limit on re.compile that will get in your way.
Hope this helps. 
Python Doc with lastgroup: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
Handy regex editor to help with future problems: https://regex101.com